# How to pass SSRS params into a URL

Tags: ssrs, ssrs-2012

I have Native SSRS configured on a 2012 instance (11.0.2100). I have two reports with images that act as buttons to toggle between the chart report and the detail report. I want to configure the action URLs to dynamically pass in parameters when switching between the reports, so that the defaults (derived from a query) are not used when switching views, the manually inputted params would persist.

I have tried the below versions of my URL and, in all cases, the default (query driven) parameters are used to run the report, not the passed in parameters.

http://internalreporting/ReportsManager/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fFinance%2fDischarge+Totals+By+Day+Less+New+Borns+-+Chart&rs:Command=Render&rs:StartDate=2015-10-01&rs:EndDate=2015-10-31

http://internalreporting/ReportsManager/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fFinance%2fDischarge+Totals+By+Day+Less+New+Borns+-+Chart&rs:Command=Render&StartDate=2015-10-01&EndDate=2015-10-31

http://internalreporting/ReportsManager/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fFinance%2fDischarge+Totals+By+Day+Less+New+Borns+-+Chart&StartDate=2015-10-01&EndDate=2015-10-31

http://internalreporting/ReportsManager/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fFinance%2fDischarge+Totals+By+Day+Less+New+Borns+-+Chart&StartDate=10/1/2015&EndDate=10/31/2015

Any ideas on where I'm formatting my URLs incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I don't have an SSRS server handy at the moment to test/confirm this, so I'm going a bit off-the-cuff here, and might not be 100% spot-on)

I've never had luck with using the ReportManager URLs when I want to pass in specific parameters. Try using the ReportServer URLs instead.

[BOL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155391.aspx) gives this example format for passing dates using the ReportServer URLs:
`http://myserver/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fProduct_and_Sales_Report_AdventureWorks&SellStartDate=7/1/2005`